# Using erb inside erb at Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, erb

Using modified version of http://railscasts.com/episodes/30-pretty-page-title for easier page heading and title.

Every page gets a `<% title "insert heading here" %>`.
Via a helper

```
def title(page_title)
  content_for(:title) { page_title }
end
```

I can use it for page title and the headings of the single pages.

Also want to modify the view of my devise setup, but got stuck at the user edit page.
The standard heading is `<h2>Edit <%= resource_name.to_s.humanize %> </h2>`.

Tried the obvious

`<% title "Edit <%= resource_name.to_s.humanize %>" %>`

But this dont work.

Any idea or suggestions?
thanks in advance
dennym

Comment: How about <% title "Edit #{resource_name.to_s.humanize}" %>? when using double quotes you can parse ruby inside #{} within a string

Comment: thank you, that works. Put it as answer so i can give you the rep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

`<% title "Edit #{resource_name.to_s.humanize}" %>?`

when using double quotes you can parse ruby inside #{} blocks inside of a string. This won't work when using a string with single quotes (') only double (").